# iCloud Tabs no longer a feature in Safari 13?

Tags: icloud, safari, tabs

Prior to updating to Safari 13, iCloud Tabs was a feature that, when turned on **and** on clicking the tabs button on "Desktop" Safari, would show you tabs that were open on other devices at the bottom of the list.

Here’s how they used to work per Apple's support documentation: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202530

I no longer see this list of tabs.

As of this writing, I am running Safari 13.0.1 on 10.14.6.

Comment: +1 Just noticed this myself. Has to be a bug :(

Comment: What versions of Safari are you using on your other devices?

Comment: I’m experiencing the same thing. I’ve recently upgraded to Safari 13.0.1 on macOS 10.14.6, while my iPhone is running iOS 13.0.0. Safari on both of my Macs, and my iPhone, see no iCloud Tabs at all.

Comment: Same thing, I am running iOS 13.1 on iPhone XS, iPadOS 13.1 on iPad Pro (2018) and macOS 10.14.6 on MacBook Pro. Reported this to Apple during beta testing, issue since beta5... just got ignored...

Comment: My two Macs (one 10.14.6 and one 10.15beta) both show iCloud tabs in Safari 13.  But they are gone from my iPhone 6+ which will never run iOS13.  I don't think this is a bug - rather it is a consequence of Apple's linking of service upgrades to OS upgrades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Reddit user [claims](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/d95h6f/psa_icloud_tabs_in_safari_13_do_not_work_and_wont/) Apple support said they won't sync until your Mac is running Catalina.

Answer (score 9):

I noticed this problem a while ago, but didn't dig into it until now. I am using iOS 13.3 and trying to get tabs from 10.13.6.

The [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202530) clarifies what should work and what will not work:

> iCloud Tabs works between devices running iOS 13 or iPadOS and macOS
>   Mojave 10.14.4 or later, or between devices running iOS 12 or earlier
>   and macOS Mojave 10.14.3 or earlier.

Apple's [What's new in the updates for macOS Mojave](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209149#macos10144) page does not mention changes that would make things incompatible, but here is a [much more detailed break down](https://eclecticlight.co/2019/03/26/what-has-changed-in-the-mojave-10-14-4-update/) of the 10.14.4 update.

So:

Catalina & iOS 13 - iCloud Tabs should work

Mojave 10.14.4 & iOS 13 - iCloud Tabs should work

**Any version of macOS less than Mojave 10.14.4 won't work without iOS 13 for iCloud Tabs.**

If you're running iOS 12, then don't go above Mojave 10.14.3 or you will not have iCloud Tabs anymore.

Comment: This probably should be the chosen answer; at least, it explains the situation I'm experiencing, which led me to this thread. In discussion of this in an Apple community forum, it was stated that this has to do with encryption: earlier macOS/iOS versions didn't encrypt tabs, newer ones do.

Comment: +1 that this should be the accepted answer.  I believe that when I last looked at that support page, it did not detail the specifics of iOS / macOS version compatibility.  It's unfortunate that my iOS devices stuck on <= iOS 12 will not sync tabs anymore with my laptop and desktop which are on newer software...

Comment: It's always the same bullshit with Apple products. Very clarifying answer anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am in the exact same situation, two iOS 12 devices and a macOS 10.14.6 machine. When running Safari 13.0.2 on my MacBook Pro I cannot see the iCloud tabs of my iOS devices, but the iOS devices can see each other's tabs.
Download the Safari Technology Preview, which is version 13.1.2, and I can confirm that the iCloud tabs work again as expected. I can see the Safari tabs that are open on my iOS tabs devices again on my Mac.
We'll have to wait until Safari 13.1.2 becomes available.

Comment: Is that still the case in November? I just installed Safari 13.0.3 on Mojave 10.14.6, and I'm still unable to see the iCloud Tabs.  Might consider the preview if it does indeed fix the problem.

Comment: I can't answer that question unfortunately, as I've since upgraded my Mac to Catalina. I can confirm that I still can't see the Safari tabs that I have open on my iOS 12 device from my Mac.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  So your Catalina Mac is running the latest official Safari build (which I presume is the same as Mojave, 13.0.03)?  If that's the case, then whenever our Safari applications are updated to 13.1.2 (regardless of which version of MacOS we are running), iOS 12 tabs should come back.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it on my side now so I will propose my solution. 
I used to beta test macOS Catalina on an external SSD connected via T3 to my MacBook Pro. 
Naively, I logged in with my AppleID on that account and turned on all things iCloud.

For quite understandable (now) reasons the two logins from the same machine in two different macOSs created a conflict in the sync. 
I booted today from that disk, signed out from my AppleID, saving a copy of the (possibly) not uploaded things to a folder which then I emailed me, and then rebooted into my main disk with Mojave.

Headed into System Preferences > iCloud, turned Safari back on and, after a few minutes, everything started working again. 
Maybe you have a similar situation, or even another machine which is just logged in with the same AppleID.

I hope this sheds some light at least.

Comment: I noticed a day or two ago after I updated Safari for desktop on Mojave, I was able to see my iCloud tabs. However, I have updated one desktop machine (a MacBook) to Catalina. So I’m not for sure if I’ve been safari solve the issue or is updating the Catalina solve the issue even though the machine I saw iCloud tablet was **not** upgraded to Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

A work-around: save all open tabs into a bookmark folder; they should miraculously appear in your bookmarks across all the other devices.

To save all tabs: If you're on |Safari on iPhone or iPad|, long-click on the bookmarks icon and you will be met with: "Add Bookmarks for X Tabs." If you're on |Safari on Mac|, go to the Bookmarks menu and choose "Add Bookmarks for These X Tabs..."

If your bookmarks sync nicely, the folder just created will appear across all devices. Good job!

The end.

If bookmark sync'ing is not happening for you, go for the longer work-around detailed below.

Longer work-around: copy contents of the newly-created, saved-tabs bookmark folder onto the clipboard. Now paste the urls into a note in the notes app (that should sync easily).

To copy the tabs from |Safari on iPhone or iPad| to |Safari on Mac|: navigate to the bookmarks folder that you just created and long-click on it. Now choose "Copy Contents." Lo and behold, the urls of the tabs are now in the clipboard.

Note: I don't know how to copy a bookmark folder to clipboard on |Safari on Mac|.